# Asp.net datagrid, set width of columns

Tags: asp.net

I have the following asp.net table, created using a datagrid:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"  CodeFile="View.aspx.vb" Inherits="MDGRenewals.page_views"  %>
<%@ Register Src ="~/Webcontrols/Admin/Users/RoleManager.ascx" tagprefix="mdg" TagName="rolemanager" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentMain" runat="server">
        <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
            <p><asp:datagrid id="DataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3">

                <ItemStyle CssClass="DGR_ITEM"></ItemStyle>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="DGR_HEADER"></HeaderStyle>

                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Username">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("user_id")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>

                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Page">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Hyperlink id="Link1" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem("page_name")%>'></asp:Hyperlink>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>

                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="View Count">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label id="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem("Count")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateColumn>

                    </Columns>

                </asp:datagrid></P>
        </form>
</asp:Content>
```

My problem is that I want to be able to set the widths of the columns, but I have not been able to do this.

As you can see from the code, I have tried:

```
                <ItemStyle Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
                <HeaderStyle  Width="200px"></HeaderStyle>
```

but it does not respond to this.

I have edited the post to contain the css and the commends to use css:

```
.DGR_HEADER
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 11px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: default;
    color: black;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: LightSteelBlue;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:15px;
}


.DGR_ITEM
{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: xx-small;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: default;
    color: black;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: silver;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: datagrids just render plain html `<table>`. Have you tried using css?

Comment: @balanza yes I have tried but it does not respond to the changes

Comment: @Alex, try applying a min-width through CSS to the td. That should do it

Comment: @alex please check out the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. You can set width of column like this

```
ItemStyle-Width="30"
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Username" ItemStyle-Width="30">
```

Comment: @Mairaj_Ahmad where would I include that in the file?

Comment: You have to set this as column property.

Comment: @Mairaj_Ahmad but where would I put that in the code eg I have tried '<Columns ItemStyle-Width="30">' but it caused an error

Comment: Here <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Username" ItemStyle-Width="30">

Answer (score 2):

Both ItemStyle-Width and HeaderStyle didn't work for me... until I made my grid wide enough that it had "room" to expand the columns in question.

I kept setting the column width to 400px, and nothing would change!

Then I set my WHOLE GRID to 4000px, and oila, now that column is actually 400px.  All the columns were squished together, so it couldn't grow that one column.

This is probably not everybody's answer, but try it if you can't get these properties to work.

Answer (score 0):

As datagrids just render plain html `<table>`, you can use css:

```
table td {
    width: 200px;
}
```

For referencing a single table, you can place this directly in the `aspx` file (or `ascx` or whaterver)

```
#<%= this.DataGrid1.ClientID %> td {
    width: 200px;
}
```